Entity version update fails in JPA integration test when using @Transactional and @Rollback
I'm trying to implement an integration test in Spring for an updateById operation of a Beer entity, which has a version property annotated with @Version.
Context:

I'm not using MockMvc but directly testing with beerRepository and
beerController.
An H2 database loads 3 Beer entities on startup.
The test class is annotated with @SpringBootTest, while the specific
test uses @Transactional and @Rollback to ensure database state rolls
back after execution.

Test flow:

Retrieve the first beer through beerRepository to get a valid UUID.
Map the Beer object to a BeerDTO object using the mapper.
Set the beerName property of beerDTO to a new value.
Call updateById on beerController with the UUID and modified beerDTO.
Assert multiple conditions, including that version is incremented by
1.

Issue:
The test fails on the version assertion. Expected value is 1, but the actual value is 0.
Observations:

The test passes if I remove @Rollback and @Transactional.
The test also passes if I use saveAndFlush instead of save in
BeerServiceJPA.

Could anyone explain why this happens and how I might fix it? I believe @Transactional and @Rollback make sense here, as an update should ideally be rolled back after the test.
Here’s the relevant code (simplified for brevity):
entities/Beer
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Beer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(length = 36, columnDefinition = "varchar", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private String beerName;
    private BeerStyle beerStyle;
    private String upc;
    private Integer quantityOnHand;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;
}


repositories/BeerRepository
public interface BeerRepository extends JpaRepository<Beer, UUID> {
}

services/BeerService
public interface BeerService {

    void updateBeerById(UUID beerId, BeerDTO beer);
}


services/BeerServiceJPA
@Service
@Primary
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BeerServiceJPA implements BeerService {
    private final BeerRepository beerRepository;
    private final BeerMapper beerMapper;


    @Override
    public void updateBeerById(UUID beerId, BeerDTO beer) {
        beerRepository.findById(beerId).ifPresent(foundBeer -> {
            foundBeer.setBeerName(beer.getBeerName());
            foundBeer.setBeerStyle(beer.getBeerStyle());
            foundBeer.setUpc(beer.getUpc());
            foundBeer.setPrice(beer.getPrice());
            beerRepository.save(foundBeer);
        });
    }

}


controllers/BeerController
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class BeerController {

    public static final String BEER_PATH = "/api/v1/beer";
    public static final String BEER_PATH_ID = BEER_PATH + "/{beerId}";

    private final BeerService beerService;

    @PutMapping(BEER_PATH_ID)
    public ResponseEntity updateById(@PathVariable("beerId")UUID beerId, @RequestBody BeerDTO beer){

        beerService.updateBeerById(beerId, beer);

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


tests/controllers/BeerControllerIT
@SpringBootTest
class BeerControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    BeerController beerController;

    @Autowired
    BeerRepository beerRepository;

    @Autowired
    BeerMapper beerMapper;


    @Rollback
    @Transactional
    @Test
    void updateExistingBeer() {
        Beer beer = beerRepository.findAll().get(0);
        Integer version = beer.getVersion();
        BeerDTO beerDTO = beerMapper.beerToBeerDto(beer);
        beerDTO.setId(null);
        beerDTO.setVersion(null);
        final String beerName = "UPDATED";
        beerDTO.setBeerName(beerName);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = beerController.updateById(beer.getId(), beerDTO);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(204));

        Beer updatedBeer = beerRepository.findById(beer.getId()).get();
        System.out.println(updatedBeer);
        assertThat(updatedBeer.getBeerName()).isEqualTo(beerName);
        assertThat(updatedBeer.getVersion()).isEqualTo(version+1);
    }
}


This happens because the value of the @Version field is updated only when the entity is written to the database. This is necessary to track changes to the entity from other transactions.
When writing an entity to the database, Hibernate executes the following query:
UPDATE beer SET version=?, <setting other fields> WHERE id=? AND version=?

This query returns the number of records updated. This can be either 1, in case the database version of the entity is the same, i.e. no other transaction updated the entity, or 0, if the database version of the entity does not match its version in the persistence context, which happens when the entity is updated by another transaction, and Hibernate throws OptimisticLockException.
The moment when the entity is written to the database is determined by the flush strategy. By default, FlushMode.AUTO is used, in which Hibernate tries to keep the entity in the persistence context for as long as possible and flushes it to the database, only at the end of the transaction, or before JPQL, HQL or SQL queries, or unless the persistence context is manually flushed to the database with the flush() command.
In your case, the call to updateById()
ResponseEntity responseEntity = beerController.updateById(beer.getId(), beerDTO);

does not immediately execute the UPDATE command, it is postponed until the end of the transaction, which in your case started at the beginning of the test and will end only after its completion, since you marked the test with the @Transactional annotation.
And calling findById()
Beer updatedBeer = beerRepository.findById(beer.getId()).get();

does not execute the SELECT command, since the entity is already in the persistence context, from where you get the updated values of all fields except @Version.
To solve this problem, you can either flush the persistence context manually before reading the updated version of the entity:
entityManager.flush();
Beer updatedBeer = beerRepository.findById(beer.getId()).get();

Or read the new version using JPQL, HQL or SQL query:
TypedQuery<Beer> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Beer b WHERE b.id = :id", Beer.class);
typedQuery.setParameter("id", beer.getId());
Beer updatedBeer = typedQuery.getSingleResult();

For more detailed information, see Hibernate User Guide.

Thank you very much! You've been really clear. So, this is happening due to the caching policy. That's why my solution works using the "saveAndFlush" method (2nd observation). However I guess it isn't the best way to solve it because it will downgrade the performances flushing every time an update operation is called. Am I right? Still, I have a doubt. In the test context we know that the transaction ends at the end of the test. What about a normal logic flow in a RESTful API? How can I identify the end of a transaction so that I'm sure the entity has been flushed into the database?

@Zanarkand A transaction begins the first time a method or class annotated with the @Transactional annotation is called, and ends when that method completes. By default, a transaction extends to all other calls within that method.

@Zanarkand Because you made the updateExistingBeer() method transactional, all operations that occur before that method completes are transactional, meaning you have one transaction that lasts through your entire test method.

@Zanarkand If you remove the @Transactional annotation from the updateExistingBeer() method, it will no longer be transactional, and transactionality will remain only on calls to JPA repository methods, and you will have four transactions: BeerRepository.findAll(), BeerRepository.findById(), BeerRepository.save(), and BeerRepository.findById() again.

oh ok so to summarize, the update of the property annotated with @Version is done by the dbms when the entity is flushed into the db. The flush happens at the end of a transaction or before a JPQL, HQL or SQL query. Is this correct?

@Zanarkand Almost, the property is updated by Hibernate, not the DBMS.

Well, it's hibernate that updates it through the sql script? I mean, hibernate doesn't update the version property in the persistence context. The update is done when the entity if flushed into the db only?

@Zanarkand Yes, hibernate updates the @Version field only when flushing to the database.
